I'm using the SvgUri package to render images. But not able to see while the app taken but connected via usb is working
This how I have imported
import Detail_R_Arrow from '../assets/images/detailRarrow.svg';


export {
  Back_Arrow,}

This is my import statement
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';
This how I have defined
<SvgUri
source={Nsettings_Image}
/>

This is my metro Config File
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const config = {};
module.exports = mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config);
I have tried this config also
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config');
module.exports = (async () => {
 const {
   resolver: { sourceExts, assetExts },
 } = await getDefaultConfig();
 return {
   transformer: {
     babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
   },
   resolver: {
     assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== 'svg'),
     sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'],
   },
 };
})();

but it doesn't works
only via connected in usb its work but once I taken as APK I cant see the SVG images what should I do
